# On change select send id?

Tags: angular

```
<select class="form-control" type="text" required  (change)="onChangeLov($event)">>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor ="let contact of contacts">{{contact.id}} - {{contact.name}}, {{contact.ptechnologyName}}, {{contact.mainlocationName}}  </option>
</select>
```

I have this what i want is to send `onChangeLove($event)` only `contact.id` from ngFor ... any suggestion how can i  do that?

Im using angular 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the id in the option's value property. When you select an option it will be sent as the target of the event that is emitted by (change) event emitter.

You can get that value in your function through event.target['value']. Here is an example:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  template: `

  <select class="form-control" type="text" required  (change)="onChange($event)">>
        <option value="{{ contact.id }}"
            *ngFor ="let contact of contacts">
            {{contact.id}} - {{contact.name}}
        </option>
  </select>  
  `
})

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  contacts = [
    {id: 1, name: 'one'},
    {id: 2, name: 'two'},
    {id: 3, name: 'three'},
    {id: 4, name: 'four'}    
  ];

  onChange(e) {
    console.log('e: ', e.target['value']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a model to tour select, example: `myModel`. And add a `ngValue` to your options so the select's model can get it's value.

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="myModel" required (ngModelChange)="onChangeLove($event)">>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let contact of contacts" [ngValue]="contact.id">{{contact.id}} - {{contact.name}}, {{contact.ptechnologyName}}, {{contact.mainlocationName}}</option>
</select>
```

In component, just:

```
onChangeLove() {
     console.log(this.myModel);
}
```